# BGP control plane information in MPLS VPN

Tags: networking, network-protocols, vpn, bgp

I am learning about MPLS VPN networks. From my understanding an IGP runs on all core routers (P and PE), while BGP runs on all PE routers. Once the IGP has conveyed reachability information to all routers, and all routers have converged, the exact labels to be used to transfer packets are assigned using LDP.

My doubt is, how are BGP control packets transmitted between PEs.

There are two options.
1. To use the Label switched paths between PEs.
2. To use normal IP forwarding through the P routers.

Which of these two methods is actually used?
If both can be used how does the PE router make a decision on which one to use?
Do we have to manually configure it in the router?
Do these answers vary for different routers like Juniper, Cisco etc. ?

Comment: This question is off-topic and should have been asked on [sf]

Comment: I checked the meta site before posting the question.  It was mentioned that any question regarding the theoretical aspect of networking has to be asked in StackOverflow, and only questions pertaining to actual implementation on a system has to be asked in ServerFault. Please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: First, let me say that it's a terrible shame that the [so] FAQ doesn't cover networking... deciding where to ask networking questions is complicated, and it's great that you looked at meta before asking.  Quoting from a [good meta question about this issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88047/#answer-88055): Questions about professional equipment (e.g. Cisco routers), or about complex server or multi-client setups, belong on [sf].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My doubt is, how are BGP control packets transmitted between PEs.
>   There are two options:
>
> 1. To use the Label switched paths between PEs.
> 2. To use normal IP forwarding through the P routers.
>
> If both can be used how does the PE router make a decision on which one to use?

LSPs are preferred over per-hop IP forwarding, if an LSP is available.

> Do we have to manually configure it in the router?

By 'it', do you mean configure use of the LSP for BGP control-plane information?  It happens automatically on a Cisco IOS box

> Do these answers vary for different routers like Juniper, Cisco etc. ?

Cisco will send BGP information through an LDP LSP, as long as the BGP endpoint prefix has an label binding.

I can't remember Juniper's behavior off-hand, they offer somewhat more granular control over LSP behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mike. Just the kind of clarification I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

BGP uses TCP te setup its connection and to send their packets to his neighbors.
This means that your neighbors need to see each other on layer 3 (ip) level.

I hope this is the info that you needed.

see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Border_Gateway_Protocol 
section "operation" for more details on this matter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer smignon.  As per my understanding, PE-PE, P-P and P-PE reachability information is first converged via IGP and then BGP communication starts. If that is the case, it should be possible to run LDP and assign labels and have the Label Switched Paths ready before the commencement of BGP communication. If that is so, isn't it wiser to use Label switching as opposed to traditional IP forwarding, as IP forwarding entails more cost (longest prefix matching), as compared to Label Switching.